# Is there a way to undo software updates?

Tags: google-chrome, update-manager

I recently* updated my installation of Google Chrome. This turns out to have been a mistake - apparently the latest version (41) is very unstable when using developer tools. Since I'm a web developer, this is unacceptable.

The thing is, I haven't restarted Chrome since I updated it, so I'm still running version 40. Is there any way to roll back the software update before I am required to restart Chrome?

*Not sure exactly how long ago; may not have been all that recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep- or revert to an older version of your software, the most convenient way is to use `Synaptic` Package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, open `Synaptic`, look up `Google Chrome`, select it and choose from the menu: "Package" > "Properties", choose the "Versions" tab. Here you can see what versions are available. In my case, that is only the version you do not want (since I run 14.04, If I remember well you run 12.04):

[image]

In your case, the earlier version will be listed as well, I will use the example on `Firefox` here to show how to return to an earlier version:

- Select your package form the list
- Choose from the menu: "Package" > "Force Version"
- Choose your preferred version:

  [image]

  Apply the changes
- To make sure the package will not be updated, choose from the menu: "Package" > "Lock version":

  [image]

More information on how to keep- or revert to previous packages can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

Comment: That's a great answer. If Google weren't such a terrible company, I'm sure it would work fine. But they don't make previous versions available in Package Manager, so the "Force Version" menu option isn't available. : (

Also, for what it's worth, I am running 14.04.

Comment: @WilsonF I don't know the quality of the source, but did you see this one? http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old seems usable and 40 is listed as `.deb` installer.

Comment: I downloaded it, but I'm not going to install it until I find a virus checker for Ubuntu. Last thing I need is adware or something on my work computer.

Comment: I'm not seeing the previous version of chrome either.