# Topbar appindicators glitching out

Tags: 16.04, indicator, budgie

For a few months I have had this problem that my topbar appindicator icons are glitching out.

A few days ago I had 3 slack icons where only one worked. And most of the time some icons overlap.

[image: crowded icons]

I am currently on Ubuntu Budgie 16.04.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

This is my topbar [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwdH2.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bum update. Install Synaptic package manager with `sudo apt install synaptic` and undo the latest software update with [Is there a way to undo software updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596554/), then use `apt-mark hold <package-name>` to prevent the same update from coming back again.

To restart the Budgie top panel run the following command:

```
nohup budgie-panel --replace&
```

To reset the entire Budgie top panel back to its default settings run the following commands:

```
budgie-panel --replace --reset # afterwards press Enter, then press Ctrl+C  
nohup budgie-panel --replace&
```

Comment: If you read my comments and my question, you can maybe understand that this has nothing to do with this problem. You can literally see my configuration included by my question.

Comment: Yes, I tried with **one** click all my icons are gone because I only have **one** appindicator applet. I'm for real not sure if you're trolling me or genuinely trying to help. Thanks for the good intentions but this is not the answer I'm looking for.