# Why taskbar doesn't appear properly on Ubuntu Budgie desktop?

Tags: 18.04, taskbar, budgie

[image]Suddenly my taskbar have a bug when I start my computer!I remember that I did updates at last time that I used Budgie working good.However,it isn't possible to find a start menu and clock on my top taskbar.I tried some commands like `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install gnome` `sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop` but nothing happens!I would like if someone helps me...Thanks.

Comment: That commands alone do nothing. `gnome` is not a package and `budgie-desktop` is already installed (it's the default desktop in your Ubuntu derivative), reinstalling it *may* have some effect but better post a screenshot showing what the problem really is.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I don't know how to post a screenshot here.Without main menu I don't know how to access some apps yet.My desktop just show quicknote and power button on taskbar and apps that I've fixed on appbar.

Comment: Take a photo with your phone if nothing else wortks, upload it to a photo hosting service like Imgur then [edit] and post the link.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I found an app!You can see my interface above now!

Comment: Nice. I hope someone can suggest a course of action. unfortunately I'm not familiar with that desktop so I don;'t know what should and what shouldn´t be there. Normal system updates are unlikely to disrupt the desktop. Settings by the user or something users install might. There's no harm in reinstalling the desktop though: `sudo apt install --reinstall budgie-desktop` (`apt`should be used now instead of `apt-get`, it has been like that for years now).

Comment: There's no need to reinstall anything before you try restarting the missing Budgie top panel.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks for your tip but this command doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I wasn't really expecting it to do anything significant but I was confident that karel's answer would work. It didn't? If so I think you may have uninstalled something or changed some setting / removed elements, etc. I don't know, never used that desktop.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I managed to solve it.

Comment: @karel I see. I'm keeping this as favorite in case something similar pops up. It's a... funny desktop of which I know almost nothing. I might try it someday.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Please visit this [Budgie chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85629/discussion-between-karel-and-gabriela-garcia) to continue the discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bum update. Install Synaptic package manager with `sudo apt install synaptic` and undo the latest software update with [Is there a way to undo software updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596554/), then use `apt-mark hold <package-name>` to prevent the same update from coming back again.

To restart the Budgie top panel run the following command:

```
nohup budgie-panel --replace&
```

To reset the entire Budgie top panel back to its default settings run the following commands:

```
budgie-panel --replace --reset # afterwards press Enter, then press Ctrl+C  
nohup budgie-panel --replace&
```

Comment: If this works, you're done. Otherwise if there are any applets missing from the budgie top panel, there is a way to restore the missing applets to the panel one applet at a time. For example it is possible to add/remove only the clock applet,

Comment: thanks for your tips,but nothing happens yet...I've just restart Budgie top panel and it don't works.I think I won't restart the entire Budgie desktop meanwhile cause I don't know how to take back my settings if I don't get success.What do you think?

Comment: There a possibility *your* settings caused the issue. Isn't it better to start over? You can reapply the changes one at a time...

Comment: Wooow thanks karel! It works! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @karel yeah!It was awswered by your nice tips!I will check this mark to green on others questions too...I'm just a newbie here,sorry for my inconvenience.